# Tracking of progress in long process of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have a very heavy graphical issue to perform, and I need to be able to show an onscreen progress bar and also prevent the browser from getting "freeze". 
I understand that tight looping is blocking the UI, and JavaScript is single threaded, so I using setTimeout in order to perform some graphical testing as follow:

```
function FG_ShowHM(y) {
   for(var x=0 ; x<100 ; x++) {
     if(FG_TreeH[y*100+x]=="") { 
       FG_hmctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)"; 
     }
     else { 
       var col=DegToCol(FG_min,FG_max,FG_TreeH[y*100+x]);
       FG_hmctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+col.r+","+col.g+",0,1)"; 
     }

     FG_hmctx.fillRect(x*3,y*3,3,3);
   }

   ProgBT+=0.5;
   y++; 

   if(y<100) { 
    window.setTimeout(FG_ShowHM(y),100);  // move on
   }
   else { 
     XPW(); 
   }
 }
```

And a call to that function from within another function:

```
window.setTimeout(FG_ShowHM(0));
```

**NOTE:** PW() is just a shortcut to jQuery functions that creating the "please wait  evement, and XPW is just a shortcut to remove the "please wait" window.

For some reason the UI is still stack without possibility to show any progress, and more than that, after few seconds the browser get completely "freeze"... 
I have tried many many ways to solve this issue, but without success.... I would like to know what is the best way to show up progress in such a long operation, or at least prevent the browser from getting "freeze".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `requestAnimationFrame` ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame))?

Comment: Ofcourse, the animation moving as I pressing the keyboard arrows, but the divs around it not responding to any change, and also the progress <div> is not showing up... Bu tI may try it on this (I using THREE.js here as well, sorry for my confusing)

Comment: Here there is also problem with the for loop which causing the browser to get stack...

Comment: Is it possible to create a small jsFIddle for better understanding?

Comment: https://www.crazygao.com/Easy3D/Problem.htm -> you shall wait till the black background will become white (this is when the "ground" is loaded), then when you click with the green square on it, you will see the problem.... (ignoring the fact that the loading in the beginning - "0.00% is not moving - but if I will get solution for the bigger problem, this will be solved too). NOTE: The code is bit large, so to make the life easier, look at the script "Forest.js" - there it get stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you use `window.setTimeout`. As a first argument it expects a function and a number as a 2nd. When you do `window.setTimeout(FG_ShowHM(y),100);` you actually don't pass a function as a parameter but execute it and the result of the execution pass to `window.setTimeout`. As a result - you have an infinite recursion.
To fix it - correct the way of calling `window.setTimeout` to

```
window.setTimeout(function() { FG_ShowHM(y) }, 100);
```

**Note**: there are a lot of places in your code of such `window.setTimeout` usage. So be attentive.

Read more about `window.setTimeout` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).